# How to define Periodic updated value without var definition in scala

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to implement that periodic updated value without var definition.

Let's say If I have web server and have to do other server's health check in it to handle user requests. the health check result would be referenced by every user request action.
It'll be huge cost if you do the health check everytime new request is handled, instead I want to update health check result value at most once per 5min.

It is easy If I use `var` to implement this.

```
  private var result = false
  private var lastUpdated = 0L
  private val INTERVAL = 1000L * 60 * 5

  def helthCheckResult = {
    System.currentTimeMillis() match {
      case currentTime if currentTime > lastUpdated + INTERVAL =>
        result = !result // actual code should call heathcheck impl
        lastUpdated = currentTime
        result
      case _ =>
        result
    }
  }
```

or with Akka

```
class HeathCheckActor(implicit system: ActorSystem) extends Actor {
  private var result = false
  system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds,5 minutes,self,"update")
  def receive = {
    case "update" if sender == self =>
      result = !result // actual code should call heathcheck impl
    case "get" =>
      sender ! result
  }
}
```

they are using `var` to hold result state. What I want to achieve is implementing this without `var`.

Is there any way to do this?

any kind of Info/Hint would be appreciated.

**Edited**

It was bit bad example to ask what I want to achieve.
Let's say If the `result` is not simple finate state like `Boolean` but `Int`. `result` could be any value Int cloud represent.
In another way to say, things like Akka [FSM](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html) can't be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do in this cases and using Akka is to use (and sometimes abuse) [context.become](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#become-unbecome)

In your case

```
override def receive: Receive = receiveWithLastResult(false)

def receiveWithLastResult(lastResult: Boolean): Receive = {
    case "update" if sender == self =>
      context.become(receiveWithLastResult(!lastResult))
    case "get" =>
      sender ! result
  }
```

In the case of the plain function, you could just receive the previous values, and return the new ones

```
  case class YourValues(result: Boolean, lastUpdated: Long)
  def helthCheckResult(previous: YourValues) = {
    System.currentTimeMillis() match {
      case currentTime if currentTime > lastUpdated + INTERVAL =>

        YourValues(result = !previous.result, lastUpdated = currentTime)

      case _ =>
        previous
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please provide code which is the place holding the value?  I'm feeling your code is just moving `var` to somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

At first it is important to know why you want that, as using a var to hold the state is an absolutely valid way, particularly for actors, which are also meant for state isolation.

Then, to avoid a var -or "holding state" in general- it is important to get an understanding why the state is held at all.

Who is interested in it? Who queries it, when, and why? Who reacts on state changes?

Then perhaps it would be valid to simply replace the "state" in the var by an observer concept, where interested parts are "notified about state changes" instead.